# Build apk in Travis CI failed for "Instrumentation failed"

Tags: android, travis-ci

Build apk failed in Travis CI. But sometimes it can build successfully, especially in night. I'm not sure it is a network error or other reasons.

```
SEVERE: APKit-AdkInstrumentor(1): extracting the apk failed rc = 1
Throwable occurred: aC: extracting the apk failed rc = 1
    at aG.a(SourceFile:199)
    at aG.a(SourceFile:155)
    at aG.a(SourceFile:150)
    at v.a(SourceFile:142)
    at e.f(SourceFile:181)
    at e.<init>(SourceFile:88)
    at a.<init>(SourceFile:27)
    at com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.AdkInstrumentor.c(SourceFile:337)
    at com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.AdkInstrumentor.main(SourceFile:277)

Instrumentation failed

Task :mobile:autoInstrumentStagUnpinnedRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:autoInstrumentStagUnpinnedRelease'.
Process 'command '/home/travis/build/app-android/mobile/build/tmp/prepareApkit/dynatrace-mobile-agent-android-7.2.4.1262/Android/auto-instrumentor/instrument.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 5
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure the build is working fine sometimes, I think it may be related to the third party of the application ( I think you want to make sure the Dynatrace Gradle plugin, you should clean and sync your project works successfully then check with Travis-ci configuration)

also, need to check does Travis-ci support this kind of application related to third-party applications

as seen from the link

https://answers.dynatrace.com/questions/213065/auto-instrument-apk-failed.html

You are still using the auto-instrumentor version 7.1.10.2332. If you are using the Dynatrace Gradle plugin, you should clean and sync your project. This behavior should force Android Studio to use the new plugin version.

To troubleshoot your problem we need the full log file. The problem occurs in a 3rd party tool and the root cause is not visible in the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I use `com.dynatrace.tools:android:7.2.4.1262`.